# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.' ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am trying to connect my ASP.NET Core 6 application to SQL Server, but I get an error on the connection string. Does anyone have experience with .NET 6 that could help?

This is my code in my class (`book.cs`). I get the ERROR where I commented in the code. And yes I have the right string in the `app.json` file

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int Pagecount { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string AutherFirstName { get; set; }
    public string AutherLastName { get; set; }

    public List<Book> GetBooks(string connectionString)
    {
        List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (connectionString);
        string selectSQL = "select BookId, Title, Isbn, PublisherName, AuthorName, CategoryName from GetBookData";
        con.Open(); // Here i get my error

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr != null)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Book book = new Book();
                book.BookId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["BookId"]);
                book.Pagecount = Convert.ToInt32(dr["pagecount"]);
                book.Title = dr["Title"].ToString();
                book.TypeName = dr["TypeName"].ToString();
                book.AutherLastName = dr["AutherLastName"].ToString();
                book.AutherFirstName = dr["AutherFirstName"].ToString();
            }
        }
        return bookList;
    }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside `GetBooks` and tell us what the value of `connectionString` is.

Comment: Also, `GetBooks` should not be an instance member of `class Book` - that makes no sense :S

Comment: ...and you aren't disposing of your `IDisposable` objects. And you're misusing `Convert`. Instead you should use `dr.GetInt32()` and `dr.GetString()` instead of using the `Object this[String]` indexer (avoid boxing, mm'key?).

Comment: When i set a Brake inside GetBooks, nothing is happening when i click on the "book" butten in lockalhost
I do not understand what u mean by the values of the con-string

Comment: He likes to know the value of your parameter `connectionString`. Either your connection string is wrong or the server is not correct configured if you get an error on connection opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually came to the answer.
Had to change the query in SQL and put part of the code into a try/catch block and it worked.

```
            string ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=RFID_Library;Integrated Security=True; TrustServerCertificate=True";
        string errormsg = null;
        List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            string selectSQL = "select BookId, Title, pagecount, AutherFirstName, AutherLastName, TypeName from GetBookData";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr != null)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Book book = new Book();
                    book.BookId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["BookId"]);
                    book.Pagecount = Convert.ToInt32(dr["pagecount"]);
                    book.Title = dr["Title"].ToString();
                    book.TypeName = dr["TypeName"].ToString();
                    book.AutherLastName = dr["AutherLastName"].ToString();
                    book.AutherFirstName = dr["AutherFirstName"].ToString();

                    bookList.Add(book);
                }
            }
            return bookList;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say configurations in .NET are annoying stuff but, let's skip that ;)

The usage of options is done after some DI logic. So basically, your problem probably is in how you are trying to get the value from `appsettings.{ENV}.json`.

You haven't attached this part of the code but when you are calling your method from the `Book.cs` class, you should do something like that:

```
new Book().GetBooks(_configuration.GetConnectionString("connStrKey"));
```

BTW this is an anti-pattern and I strongly recommend you start using the [Options Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options) to inject options and settings into your code.

So, your code should be changed to something like that:

```
public class ConnectionStrings
{
    public ConnectionStrings()
    {
        ConnectionString = string.Empty;
    }

    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class BooksRepository
{
    private readonly ConnectionStrings connectionStringsOptions;

    public BooksRepository(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> connectionOptions)
    {
        connectionStringsOptions = connectionOptions.Value;
    }

    public List<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionStringsOptions.ConnectionString);
        string selectSQL = "select BookId, Title, Isbn, PublisherName, AuthorName, CategoryName from GetBookData";
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr != null)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                bookList.Add(new Book
                {
                    BookId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["BookId"]),
                    Pagecount = Convert.ToInt32(dr["pagecount"]),
                    Title = dr["Title"].ToString(),
                    TypeName = dr["TypeName"].ToString(),
                    AutherLastName = dr["AutherLastName"].ToString(),
                    AutherFirstName = dr["AutherFirstName"].ToString()
                });
            }
        }
        return bookList;
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int Pagecount { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string AutherFirstName { get; set; }
    public string AutherLastName { get; set; }
}
```

Since you are using .net 6, update your `Program.cs` class to add the connection strings as DI Options adding the following line before the `var app = builder. Build();` statement.

```
builder.Services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
```

Example of  `appsettings.json` section

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": "localhost:1433"
  }
}
```

Comment: hey ! ant thanks but in the new .NET 6 u dont have a startup file :(so i still dont know what to do with it. and when i try do inplement ur code i still get the same error in the same place.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm used to overriding the program class to keep using startup.cs class and I forgot this difference since .net 6. I updated my answer, hope it helps you.